# Common default desktop for multiple users in Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: server, remote-desktop

Please forgive me if this question has been asked to death, but I have not been able to find a solution. Perhaps my terminology is not correct (I come from a Windows background).

I am in the process of setting up a small Ubuntu 18.04 server to act as a Web and Remote Desktop server for a small group of autistic kids. The ultimate aim is for them to learn a bit of coding and web building.

I am using xRDP so all the students can log in to the server's graphic desktop (I am using the Ubuntu MATE desktop environment). This is set up and working, and I can easily use the Windows RDP software to connect to the server from my Windows system.

All of the software I need has been installed onto the server, and my desktop has been set up with the icons and programs I want available to the students.

My question is this:
Is there a way I can 'create' a standard, default desktop that all users can/will 'inherit' or will I need to go into each login on the system and customise their desktops individually?

I have only created one user on the system so far (myself), but I would like all newly created users to get the same customisations to the desktop. Is this possible in Ubuntu 18.04?

Any assistance or guidance in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible in all releases of Ubuntu.

Place the customizations in `/etc/skel`. Place the actual .desktop files, don't try to merely drag icons.

When new users are created, the files in /etc/skel are copied into the new user's /home directory.

Note that this is a new-user solution only: If a user deletes a custom icon from their desktop, they don't get it back at next login. Meanwhile, future new users still get the icon.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is exactly what I was looking for.